# node js how to identify postman extention client request came from "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: node.js

I am using node js, express frame work and rest api
I want to know postman extention client request came from "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded"
i have completed set of work based on "x-www-form-urlencoded" option here able to get values directly like req.headers.username or req.body.username or req.params.username.
but "form-data" in this method i am not able to get values directly like req.headers.username or req.body.username or req.params.username. so i am used below code to get the values.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`         
        console.log(files);
        console.log('\n\n\n'+fields);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        //res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.send(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
```

in this reason i want to check condition request came from "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded" please help me.
and also possible to assign form.parse fields values to req.body because i have wrote functions based on req.body.

Answer (score 0):

just use req.contentType. It will give you the request content type

Comment: Thanks for your reply
console.log('conent type: '+req.contentType);
I got output as  - conent type: undefined